# Как в TextView выводить точное время посекундно?

Tags: java, android, android-textview, таймер, java-timer

В `TextView` нужно показать текущие дату и время. Время вплоть до секунды, чтобы было видно как идет время.

Answer (score 5):

Для решения этой задачи существует специальный виджет – [`TextClock`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextClock.html).

Вот простой пример:

```
<TextClock
    android:id="@+id/text_clock"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:format12Hour="dd.MM.yyyy, hh:mm:ss"
    android:format24Hour="dd.MM.yyyy, hh:mm:ss"/>
```

Атрибуты `format12Hour` и `format24Hour` задают формат времени для 12-часового формата исчисления времени и 24-часового соответственно.

`TextClock` появился в 17-й версии API, для меньших версий API можно использовать [`DigitalClock`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DigitalClock.html).

Если же Вам принципиально нужно выводить текущее время именно в `TextView`, то это можно сделать примерно так:

```
final Handler timeHandler = new Handler(getMainLooper());
final SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat =  new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy, hh:mm:ss", Locale.US);
timeHandler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        clockTextView.setText(simpleDateFormat.format(new Date()));
        timeHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
});
```